# Минимизаторы и обфускаторы для js - нужны ли они?

Tags: javascript

Хочется понять и подготовится ко всему сразу, по этому возник вопрос - нужны ли минимизаторы и обфускаторы для js? Применяете ли Вы их? Какие лучшие?

Comment: Практически все javascript библиотеки и модули обфусцируют в целях уменьшения объема кода и/или чтобы скрыть логику кода от любопытных пользователей. Поэтому решение всегда за вами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй аспект вы не рассматриваете в принципе? Навскидку, есть такая галерея - highslide.js. Базовый скрипт "размашистым почерком" занимает ~53 Kb, после упаковки (и, само собой, обфускации) - ~26 Kb.

**Обновление**

Второй аспект - это минимизация объёма, раз на первое место вы ставите сокрытие кода, и говорите только про него.

Есть и необфусцирующие минимизаторы ([пример](http://search.cpan.org/~zoffix/JavaScript-Minifier-1.11/lib/JavaScript/Minifier.pm)). Но большего сжатия можно добиться, например, заменяя имена переменных или функций на более короткие (`fitOverlayBox() => a()`, `var outlineWhileAnimating; => var b;` и т.д.) А это и есть обфускация.

Comment: Нет, все наоборот! я как раз только и рассматриваю уменьшение веса и спрашиваю опытных - пользуются ли они этим в реальных проектах? И какой лучший минимизатор?
 Минуточку... А минимизатор и обфускатор - это одно и тоже? я просто рассматриваю их, как два разных инструмента.

Comment: @klopp: Спасибо! Теперь я понял..